# How to call API when app is in background?

Tags: ios, background-process

I want to call API in my app when app goes to background the API must be call after every ten minutes in the background...

If it is possible then please let me know how to do that?

Comment: Have a look at: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/BackgroundExecution/BackgroundExecution.html

Comment: Your app cannot execute at specific intervals in the background. You can use background fetch to periodically fetch data but you can't control the interval.

Answer (score 2):

You can call the API when app enters in background.

```
- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application
{
//Call API Here...
}
```

But there are some restrictions from apple when app is in background.
Please check the below link to find out the restrictions
https://www.raywenderlich.com/143128/background-modes-tutorial-getting-started

Answer (score 0):

I had to call the API on receiving a push. So, I have added a Notification Service in target and write API call code in NotificationService class's didReceive method. Make sure to send key "mutable-content":1, inside "apps" in the APNS payload. It is working even app is killed or the background state.